# How to apply data-driven concept to user keywords in Robot Framework?

Tags: templates, keyword, robotframework

Let's assume that I have the user keyword defined for the following operations:
SEND_EMAIL
READ_EMAIL
FLAG_EMAIL
I would like to perform those actions randomly 10 times in Robot Framework.  How could I best achieve this?

For example, when I run this test a couple of times, Robot Framework could do something like
Run 1: SEND_EMAIL. READ_EMAIL, READ_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, READ_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, READ_EMAIL
Run 2: READ_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, READ_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL, SEND_EMAIL

I was hoping that Robot Framework have something like this but I don't seem to find any method to write "Pick 1 of 3 possible actions" below:

For Loop From One to Ten:
   Pick 1 of the 3 Possible Actions(SEND_EMAIL, READ_EMAIL, FLAG_EMAIL)

Comment: How does this apply to the concept of data-driven ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  String

*** Test Cases ***

Perform Test Once
    Perform Test

Perform Test Twice
    Perform Test
    Perform Test


*** Keywords ***

SEND_EMAIL
    Log SEND_EMAIL  WARN

READ_EMAIL
    Log READ_EMAIL  WARN

FLAG_EMAIL
    Log FLAG_EMAIL  WARN

Call Random
#   Generate Random String With Length 1 From Numbers 1,2 and 3
    ${random}=  Generate Random String  1  123
#   Call Keyword Randomly Using If/Else If/Else
    Run Keyword If  ${random} == 1  SEND_EMAIL
    ... ELSE IF     ${random} == 2  READ_EMAIL
    ... ELSE        FLAG_EMAIL

Perform Test
#   Call Keyword "Call Random" 10 Times Using FOR loop
    :FOR  ${number}  IN RANGE  0  10
    \   Call Random
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Evaluate` keyword to get python to return a random number within a range. You can then use that number to pick a keyword from a list of keywords. With that, it's easy to write a keyword that picks a random keyword from a list and runs that keyword

Once you have that, you can use a loop to do that as many times as you want.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Run random email keywords ten times
| | :FOR | ${counter} | IN RANGE | 10
| | | Run one of these keywords randomly:
| | | ... | SEND_EMAIL | READ_EMAIL | FLAG_EMAIL


*** Keywords ***
| Run one of these keywords randomly:
| | [Arguments] | @{args}
| | [Documentation] | Run a random keyword from a list of keywords
| | 
| | # Get a random number to use to pick a keyword
| | ${index}= | Evaluate | random.randint(0, len(${args})-1) | random
| | 
| | # Get a keyword using the random number
| | ${keyword}= | Get variable value | ${args[${index}]}
| | 
| | # Run the keyword
| | Run keyword and continue on failure | ${keyword}
```

Note that this will appear in the log as a single test case rather than 10 test cases. You can choose to either let all 10 keywords run like in the example, or you can fail when the first keyword fails.